# Weighted multi-term aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to do a multi-term aggregation in Elasticsearch, but instead of simply counting the documents containing each set of terms, I would like it to sum the value of a third field.

So given data:

```
    f1  f2  s
    === === ===
    a   a   1
    a   b   2
    b   a   2
    a   b   1
    a   b   2
    a   a   1
    b   b   3
    a   b   3
```

I would like to do a multi-term aggregation on f1 and f2 with the sum(s) instead of a document count, on par with:

```
{
    aggs: {
        f_1_2_score: {
            multi_term: {
                terms: [{ field: "f1" }, {field: "f2"}],
                scoring: { field: "s" } // the illegal part I'm trying to replace
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yielding the following results:

```
    ...
    buckets: [
        { key: ["a", "a"], key_as_string: "a|a", doc_score: 2 },
        { key: ["a", "b"], key_as_string: "a|b", doc_score: 7 },
        { key: ["b", "a"], key_as_string: "b|a", doc_score: 2 },
        { key: ["b", "b"], key_as_string: "b|b", doc_score: 3 },
    ]
    ...
```

What is the easiest/best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try following, equivalent of `select sum(*) as s group by a, b order by s desc.`

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "key": {
        "multi_terms": {
            "terms": [
                {
                    "field": "f1"
                },
                {
                    "field": "f2"
                }
            ]
        },
        "aggs": {
            "doc_score": {
                "sum": {
                    "field": "s"
                }
            },
            "aggr_sort": {
                "bucket_sort": {
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "doc_score": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```